# repaint() not updating JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint

So I made a program where there is a GUI where the user can enter the parameters for a fireworks launch, and there is a panel in the middle of the screen where the launch is supposed to be drawn when a button is pressed. In my program however the JPanel is not updating and nothing is being drawn. The code is below

```
//This is the method that build the JPanel in the center for the launch
public JPanel buildCenter() {
    JPanel center=new JPanel();
    center.setBackground(Color.black);
    center.setVisible(true);
    return center;
}


//This is the method the build the GUI, the buttons and such are in the other panels labeled top, west, east, etc.
public void buildGUI(){
    configureSliders();
    configureRadioButtons();
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    JPanel top=new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    Fireworks.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 30));
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    top.setLayout(new BoxLayout(top, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    top.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    top.add(Fireworks);
    top.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    frame.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(1920,1080);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    panel.add(buildCenterTop(),BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(buildCenter(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(buildwest(), BorderLayout.WEST);
    panel.add(buildeast(),BorderLayout.EAST);
    panel.add(Launch, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    Launch.addActionListener(this);
}
//this is the action performed method where repaint won't work. fire is my fireworks object with the paintcomponent method for the launch.
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource().equals(Launch)) {
        setColor();
        setTime();
        setExplosion();
        fire.setVelocity(veloslider.getValue());
        fire.setTheta(thetaslider.getValue());
        buildCenter().add(fire);
        buildCenter().repaint();
        buildCenter().validate();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your `buildCenter()` method does is create an empty panel with a black background.

You then add this empty panel to the frame:

```
panel.add(buildCenter(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Then in your ActionListener you do:

```
buildCenter().add(fire);
buildCenter().repaint();
buildCenter().validate();
```

All this does is create 3 more empty panels. You don't want to create 3 more panels. You want to add components to the existing panel.

What you need to do is create a single instance of your "center" panel and then keep a variable that references this panel so you can update the panel in the future.

So you need an instance variable to be defined in your class:

```
private JPanel centerPanel;
```

Then in the buildGui() method you create the panel:

```
//panel.add(buildCenter(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
centerPanel = buildCenter();
panel.add(buildCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Then in your `ActionListener` you can add components to the center panel:

```
//buildCenter().add(fire);
//buildCenter().repaint();
//buildCenter().validate();
centerPanel.add( fire );
centerPanel.revalidate();
centerPanel.repaint();
```

Comment: Thank you but it still is not working and I can't tell why

Comment: I have no idea what your "fire" class is. If you are doing custom painting then you are probably doing it wrong if nothing appears. So forget about the "fire" class. First learn how to add a component to the panel when you click a button. Create [mcve].  What you need is a frame with a panel in the CENTER. Then you add a JButton to the SOUTH. In the ActionListener you then add a JLabel to the center panel. If the code works, great your fix your real application. If it doesn't work then you have a simple 20-30 line program to post in the forum so we can give better help.

Comment: When i tried your suggestion with the Label it worked, so does that mean the issue lies within my fire method that draws the fireworks? It worked when i created a new frame and added it to the frame in the ActionListener but it won't work when I try and add it to a panel

Comment: @JoeButler, `so does that mean the issue lies within my fire method that draws the fireworks?` - exactly, which is why you start with a standard component so you know if the problem is with the basic logic or with your custom component. `It worked when i created a new frame and added it to the frame` - because the default Layout Manager for the frame is a BorderLayout. When you add a component to the CENTER the layout manager will automatically resize the component to fill the space available in the frame.

Comment: The default layout manager for a JPanel is the FlowLayout which respects the preferred size of the component. My guess is you are doing custom painting and didn't specify the preferred size so the layout manager assumes a size of (0, 0), so there is nothing to paint. You need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the custom panel where you do the painting. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: thank you so much, I ended up changing the layout of the center panel to boarderlayout then adding my fire object to the center of the panel and it worked. Thank you for all the help